# How to get information of the apps that are installed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I programatically get the infomation about apps which are installed on my iPhone? 
(For example, the app name and the app identifier.)

Comment: In what context, as in, how and where will this information be used? Your question isn't too clear.

Comment: I just want to make statistic analyses, and find out which app people like most. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can, from your own app, see what other apps are installed on the device, the answer is, you can't (if the device isn't jailbroken).

Or, that's not entirely true. You *can* do two things:

1) Get a list of the running processes on the device. You have to try and match the process name to an app name on your own.

2) Check if there are apps that have registered known URL schemes (with `UIApplicationDelegate canOpenURL`). You have to know the URL first and then try. There are 3rd party collections of the URLs you can use (http://handleopenurl.com for example).

My experience is that when people ask this, what they want is a simple way to see all installed apps on the device, not these two somewhat limited options—and that's just not possible with a non-jailbroken iOS device.

Comment: If it was an ok answer for you, maybe you could accept it? Or at least press the "This answer was useful" button?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command just make sure to filter out the words install or deinstall and anything that starts with `gsc.something` using sed, awk, or grep.

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

This will output a list of installed on the iPhone in a list named installed-software

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software
```

Comment: anywhere in your app code under the assumption that the device your doing it on is jailbroken I would do `setuid(0); system("dpkg --get-selections > installed-software");`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do that because of sandboxed environment and as well it violets apple's rules .